# Solaris shared libraries and global variables

Tags: c++, global-variables, solaris, shared-libraries

I have an issue with global variables in shared library on Solaris. 
Consider following sample:

```
class Foo
{
public:
 Foo() { Init(); }

private:
  void Init() { // do something }
};
```

I have some code in shared library:

```
Foo g_Foo;
```

I've noticed that Foo constructor is never called on Solaris while the same code works Linux.

I'm using gcc 3.4.3 and Sun linker.

Comment: Could you post of entire code of what actually you are doing ? I don't think there is problem with OS.

Comment: I'll second that.  I've used this idiom a lot under Solaris in the past, and it has always worked.  (Admittedly, I usually compiled using Sun CC, but I really don't think that g++ is the problem.)

Comment: Are you sure this is the scenario. The code you have posted seems fine. But behavior you have mentioned makes me guess of "static initialization fiasco", the code you posted doesn't say so though.

Comment: I'm working of porting some code to Solaris. I can reproduce the issue with sample above. One more note - the same code compiled as static lib does not have this issue. It can be solved with changing Init to be public and call it from library initialization function (-z initarray=init_lib), but it is not applicable for all cases

Comment: Are you sure your library is being loaded?  I've seen issues where `env` was messed up, and loaded an older version of a development `.so`, or where a static and dynamic version of the lib exist, and it compiles with the wrong one.  I've been away from solaris long enough that I've forgotten some of the commands, but you can run a command on an executable to see what libs will be used when you run it (it prints full path information for each `.so`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating the shared object with the -G flag? e.g.
CC -G -o mylib.so myfile.cpp

If you don't specify -G, then the compiler may not initialise global variables correctly.  See compiler documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/821-1383/bkamq/index.html).

Note, the docs also say you can't use ld, but need to use CC to do the linking.